# How to code logical expression 'equals "MR" or "X" '?

Tags: java

Need help with if else statement in Java. Need the program to output when either `l.getPlot().equals("MR")` or `("X")` and if `l.getZone().equals("UP SPEC")` set the top upper limit.

Can anyone explain to me how to properly set that up so when the query is a match for MR or X it will set the top upper.

Note: If I remove `|| ("X")` it works for all the MR items but leaves all the `("X")` blank.

```
if (l.getPlot().equals("MR")) || ("X"){
                if (l.getZone().equals("UP SPEC")) {
                    limit.setTopUpper(l.getLimit());
                } else if (l.getZone().equals("LO SPEC")) {
                    limit.setTopLower(l.getLimit());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use this: `if ("MR".equals(l.getPlot()) || "X".equals(l.getPlot())) ...` you need to check equality each time.  Also, put the string literal first, to avoid a null pointer exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick because it applies the logical "or" to two conditions, instead of one condition and one bare string.

```
if (l.getPlot().equals("MR")) || (l.getPlot().equals("X")){
```

Here is an improved version (credits Tim Biegeleisen), which avoids a null pointer exception.

```
if ("MR".equals(l.getPlot()) || "X".equals(l.getPlot()))
```

If the argument to `equals()` evaluates to NULL, the result is a clean `false`.

Comment: Improved? Beg to differ. If null checks are needed, I prefer to make them explicit or use `Objects.equals`. [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)